# using html5 getusermedia to create and send webm file to server live

Tags: php, html, video, stream, live

Can anyone give me some links to help me achieve this,

I want to get the webcam video (getusermedia html5) , send that webm file(not recorded , live) to the server where it will be encoded and segmented to be broadcasted to others.

I have no idea on how to create a live stream of webm video from the cam and send it to the server .. need not be websockets

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it isn't currently possible to access browser codecs directly from JavaScript for encoding. The only way to do it would be to utilize WebRTC and set up recording on the server. I've tried this by compiling libjingle with some other code out of Chromium to get it to run on a Node.js server... it's almost impossible.

Hopefully, the Media Recorder API will be implemented by browsers, allowing access to the encoded media in the near future.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.. after searching i found that the mediarecorder api does work.. https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/ 
it saves the video as a webm file.. can i stream this file while its being recorded if its possible ?

Comment: @user3117384 I don't believe that package does streaming like you want.  Again, the APIs for capturing encoded data do not exist yet.

Comment: it records the video to a webm file right ? cant i post that file to the server when its created ?( Since the filesize will keep on increasing till the recording stops would it send the data to the server ? I was jst wondering )

Comment: @user3117384 I don't believe you can stream from that file as it is created.  I've tried this in the past.  If you find differently, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

See this link they are using websocket to transfer image stream so you can use websocket npm in nodejs 
http://www.smartjava.org/content/face-detection-using-html5-javascript-webrtc-websockets-jetty-and-javacvopencv

But i think its not possible without Websocket